# LazyInitializationException from object stored in the HTTP session

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, spring-security

I have a scenario in a Grails project where I am storing domain object in an HTTP session. This is arguably not a great practice, but I'm not in a position to change that at the moment.

The issue I'm encountering is that if I hit an unhandled exception, and then attempt to logout (authentication is using Spring Security) I will be unable to logout and will get another LazyInitialization exception (not even on the same collection as before.)

What I don't understand is what Spring Security is trying to do with these detached domain objects in the HTTP session.

If I look through the Grails docs, there are examples on how to reattach things to the Hibernate session: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html. In this case though, I don't even want to reattach these objects. I'm done with them. It seems like spring security is looking in the HTTP session and trying to do something with those objects, but I'm not sure what, or how to fix it.

Full stack trace:

```
    Line | Method
->> 1418 | writeOrdinaryObject in java.io.ObjectOutputStream
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|   1547 | defaultWriteFields  in     ''
|   1508 | writeSerialData     in     ''
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|   1547 | defaultWriteFields  in     ''
|   1508 | writeSerialData     in     ''
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|    347 | writeObject . . . . in     ''
|   1128 | writeObject         in java.util.HashMap
|    988 | invokeWriteObject . in java.io.ObjectStreamClass
|   1495 | writeSerialData     in java.io.ObjectOutputStream
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|   1547 | defaultWriteFields  in     ''
|   1508 | writeSerialData     in     ''
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|   1547 | defaultWriteFields  in     ''
|   1508 | writeSerialData     in     ''
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|   1547 | defaultWriteFields  in     ''
|   1508 | writeSerialData     in     ''
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|    347 | writeObject . . . . in     ''
|   1129 | writeObject         in java.util.HashMap
|    988 | invokeWriteObject . in java.io.ObjectStreamClass
|   1495 | writeSerialData     in java.io.ObjectOutputStream
|   1431 | writeOrdinaryObject in     ''
|   1177 | writeObject0        in     ''
|    347 | writeObject . . . . in     ''
|     74 | doFilter            in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: Nope, wrong track - Spring Security and the spring-security-core plugin aren't mucking about in your session looking for treasure or disconnected objects. There is some session usage, but only objects stored by the plugin or library are retrieved.

Comment: The 500 server error generated is:
URI
/trifleet/j_spring_security_logout

Class
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException

Message
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:

I'm not really sure what else could be the issue. :\ Everything else in the app works fine, logging out is the only place that generates an error.

Comment: Looking at the code (it's an open source project btw) line 74 of `MutableLogoutFilter` is where it loops through all of the `LogoutHandlers` to do their logout cleanup tasks, and it looks like that is the result of `session.invalidate()` being called by `SecurityContextLogoutHandler`. What server are you running on? It looks like it's serializing the session somethere (db? disk? cluster nodes?)

Comment: It's a Tomcat server. I looked at the logout filter but didn't see anything that stood out to me, I'm not sure when/where the logout handlers are registered.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Stack trace is in the original question already.

Comment: I have found that it only happens in the deployed environment on Tomcat, it doesn't happen when running a local server pointed at the same database. So I believe Burt is on the right track believe it is related to the server.